# I cant access base64_img in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I don't know why but ever time when I WANT to send a `canvas.toDataURL()`  discord deal with it like an file directory like `./data:image/`

If any one know the solution for this please let me know ,
And Sorry for the bad English but it's not my main language

Comment: Thats what the method means by data url. Try using a buffer of the image `canvas.toBuffer()`

Comment: What does ```canvas.toBuffer()``` mean?

Comment: A buffer is a stream of data which will represent your canvas image. This data can then be converted into a visible png